# RStudio makes my graphs turn grey when I expand them

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I'm using a script in RStudio which produces several graphs. This is a (very simplified) example of how it looks

```
mpg = mtcars$mpg
cyl = mtcars$disp
hp = mtcars $hp

plot(mpg, cyl)

dev.new()
plot(mpg,hp)

dev.new()
plot(hp, cyl)
```

When I run this in RStudio (using the "Source" key), the first graph stays in the "Plots" viewer in the lower right of the Rstudio window (I would actually like it to be a separate window as well if anyone knows how to do that), and the second and third graphs are produced as individual windows separate from the RStudio screen.

When I try to change the size of these windows (by pressing the full screen button in the top right corner, or by dragging the side), the most recently generated window is fine and resizes, but the previous one turns grey and the graph stops showing.

I thought it might have something to do with the fact that the graphics devices are inactive, but the most recently generated one, which rescales fine, also says it's inactive.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Edit: here is the output of sessionInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DescTools_0.99.36 dplR_1.7.1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6       mvtnorm_1.1-1      lattice_0.20-41    matrixStats_0.56.0 XML_3.99-0.3       png_0.1-7         
[7] digest_0.6.25      MASS_7.3-51.5      R.methodsS3_1.8.0  grid_4.0.0         plyr_1.8.6         signal_0.7-6      
[13] magrittr_1.5       stringi_1.4.6      rstudioapi_0.11    R.oo_1.23.0        R.utils_2.9.2      Matrix_1.2-18     
[19] boot_1.3-24        tools_4.0.0        stringr_1.4.0      compiler_4.0.0     expm_0.999-4
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide the output from `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Hi, I edited my question to include the output of sessionInfo()! Hope that helps

Comment: I'm on win10, R-4.0.1, just tested in RStudio-1.2.5042 (I know this is out of date ... I don't use RStudio daily, just emacs/ess, so it hasn't been a priority), I cannot reproduce this problem. What version of RStudio are you using?

Comment: I just updated to RStudio-1.3.959 and no change. The plot windows do go gray temporarily *while resizing*, but the moment I pause (even without letting go of the corner handle), the plot regenerates and the gray goes away. Thoughts, though not high confidence: uninstall/reinstall R and/or RStudio; do you have a graphic card that might be misbehaving? Perhaps try on an external monitor.

Comment: Man, that is so weird :( I rebooted my computer and I'm using the most current version of RStudio. I am currently using an external monitor with a laptop, and when I have RStudio on the external monitor and the plots generate on my laptop it doesn't work but when RStudio is on my laptop screen it's fine. Go figure. That's an annoying issue!

Comment: External monitors can sometimes be the source of otherwise unexplainable phenomena like this ... sorry, I have nothing to offer other than commiseration.

Comment: Haha thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a perfect answer, but here's what I found to work around it:

When you generate a number of graphics devices the most recently generated one remains "active" while the rest are inactive. If you don't close the active window and resize the others, it works fine. But if you close the active window and then try to resize the others, they just go grey. Somehow, closing the active window shuts down something and stops you from being able to resize the graphs at all. Weird.